# MongoDB c++ legacy driver 1.1.2 not working - Compiled with VS2013, Win 10, boost-1_62

Tags: c++, mongodb, boost, driver, legacy

Driver compiled successfully without problem. I coded a simple program to test the driver. Basically the following is the code:

```
static std::vector<mongo::HostAndPort> hosts = { mongo::HostAndPort("xxxxxxxx-a0.mlab.com:xxxxx"), mongo::HostAndPort("xxxxxxxx-a1.mlab.com:xxxxx") };
static mongo::DBClientReplicaSet con("rs-xxxxxxxx", hosts, 0);


std::string errmsg;
mongo::client::initialize();
con.connect();
con.auth("dbname", "userid", "password", errmsg);
```

I compiled the code with no problem. The exe couldn't start in bebug mode, giving error 0xc000a200. I was not able to debug at all. In release mode, it stopped right at starting-up. I noticed there was a boost warning in the console:

```
Assertion failed: px != 0, file C:\Boost\include\boost-1_62\boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp, line 105
```

And there was an error popup:

[MongoDB C++ Legacy Driver Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ988.gif)

I was able to choose debug and here is where the program stopped - the last line of replica_set_monitor.cpp:

```
void ReplicaSetMonitor::createIfNeeded(const string& name, const set<HostAndPort>& servers) {
    LOG(3) << "ReplicaSetMonitor::createIfNeeded " << name;
    boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lk(setsLock);
    ReplicaSetMonitorPtr& m = sets[name];
    if (!m)
        m = boost::make_shared<ReplicaSetMonitor>(name, servers);
    // Don't need to hold the lifetime lock for safeGo as
    // 1) we assume the monitor is created as the contract of this class is such that initialize()
    //    must have been called.
    // 2) replicaSetMonitorWatcher synchronizes safeGo internally using the _monitorMutex
    replicaSetMonitorWatcher->safeGo();
}
```

Please help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `mongo::client::initialize` *before* you construct any driver objects, or BSON for that matter. Move the call to `mongo::client::initialize` above where you declare the DBClientReplicaSet object.

Comment: Thanks! That's it! But now I got an exception at:

Comment: `con.auth("dbname", "userid", "password", errmsg); `: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD87F77788 in mongodrivertest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: mongo::UserException at memory location 0x00000056C6FFF070.

Comment: Program broke at: 'bool DBClientWithCommands::auth(......
                   << username << saslCommandPasswordFieldName << password_text
                   << saslCommandDigestPasswordFieldName << digestPassword));`

Comment: @Harold - Please open a new post for a new issue.

Comment: Used try... catch... and figured out the problem:

Comment: So I am trying to rebuild mongoDB driver with ssl. So many problems with OpenSSL. Here is another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165229/openssl-1-0-2j-installation-on-windows-10-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-inclu