# OpenSSL-1.0.2j installation on Windows 10 - fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lmstats.h'

Tags: openssl, failed-installation

Was following the installation steps:

`> perl Configure VC-WIN64A`
 `> ms\do_win64a`
 `> nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak`
 `> cd out32dll`
`> ..\ms\test`

Get the error at step 3.

I have successfully installed OpenSSL-1.1.0 but I need older version with the ssleay32.dll libeay32.dll files. The new version has totally different files: libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll and libssl-1_1-x64.dll.

Does anybody know more about this header file - lmstats.h? Was not able to find more information about it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Just download lmstats.h from [lmstats.h on SourceForge](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjnranW9-rPAhWnrlQKHfAdDR0QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fu%2Fearnie%2Fwinapi%2Fwinapi%2Fci%2Fmaster%2Ftree%2Finclude%2Flmstats.h%3Fformat%3Draw&usg=AFQjCNESorGMtFZQ_OQKW4Vpo96AD3pl_A&sig2=faH-u9xPfu1eJcZDuSYyug&bvm=bv.136499718,d.cGw)

and save it to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\shared